# XAMPP error figuring out?

Tags: macos, windows, filesystem, file-sharing, google-apps

I am using Google Drive to sync files for web projects that I am creating. I have a PC (Windows 7 and windows Vista) and a Mac (10.11.1).

XAMPP allows you to run PHP programs and databases on your local machine. The problem is that when I edit a file on my windows machine and then go to my mac machine and try to load the file in the browser, XAMPP gives me this error...
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drive/fireworks/fireworks.html'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in Unknown
>   on line 0

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

This problem is really annoying and I need to fix it because it is driving me nuts! If I change the file permissions, it will make it work until the next time I edit the file(s) on my windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have the key to the answer in your question. It is a permissions issue and there are at least two ways that you could fix it. Ultimately, though, it is likely that Google Drive owns the file and then when the web server in XAMPP tries to execute it, it is denied. Likely, the web server isn't even in the same group as GD and therefore the Unix permissions should end in at least 5. I suspect that setting the files to the infamous (and absolutely rightly so) 777 would correct the problem. A permissions number ending with 7 indicates that you are giving the public **full** access to read, write, and execute the script.

For a resolution, move to git. I'm not aware of anyone using Google Drive as a deployment strategy, although I'm sure someone has. I believe the most popular version control is Git, which would be good to learn anyway as you will need those skills if you work for a development shop.

A second option would be to write a little bash or Apple script to change the file permissions.

Comment: Do you know a good place to learn git? I've heard that there is a desktop app. How should I pursue git(hub)?

Comment: You can learn here: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-git. I haven't done it but it looks reasonable. Whatever you do, **don't** use a GUI (graphical user interface). Learn the command line. That is just my opinion but I think you will always be limited by the GUI. There is tons of documentation and help with git. It is actually fairly simple.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I couldn't help noticing your bio, I like it :) I'll start learning the "git". Thank you for your answer, it was well documented which made it easy to understand.

Comment: You must be a member of the Maxwell family? My parents and I have gone to several of your conferences. Your father is Steve Maxwell correct? Remarkable to meet you here!

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I'm glad I could help. Let's move further discussion off of SE - you can use the contact form on http://BluegrassPiano.com to reach out directly.